# How do pre-segwit clients evaluate segwit spends true?

Tags: segregated-witness

[Quoting Bitcoin wiki:](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script)

> A transaction is valid if nothing in the combined script triggers
> failure and the top stack item is true (non-zero).

However, P2WPKH and P2WSH scriptPubkeys are two data pushes of witness versions and witness programs with empty scriptsigs spending them. From a pre-segwit client perspective, stack is ending with data pushes which are non-true? If so how do legacy clients evaluate segwit spends true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Bitcoin scripting system, anything that is not explicitly OP_FALSE (0) is implicitly true. Because the top stack elements is not 0, it will be evaluated as true.

Comment: "The top stack item true" is just a relay policy then?

Comment: No, it is a consensus rule.